# how do I ignore a same value of a key in dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

```
cnt_lst = {     'Jojo': {'Name ': "Jojo",
                            'Phone': "0896",
                            'Email': "Jojo@email.com"},
                'Johan': {'Name ': "Johan",
                            'Phone': "0878",
                            'Email': "2@email.com"},
                'John': {'Name ': "John",
                            'Phone': "0815",
                            'Email': "3@email.com"}
                }

search = "jo"
info = False

for key, value in cnt_lst.items():   
    for subject, score in value.items():
        if search in score:
            info = True
            print("=" * 20)
            for subject, score in value.items():
                print(subject,' : ',score)

if not info:
    print("\nNo info was found!")
```

The output of the above code is:

```
====================
Name   :  Jojo
Phone  :  0896
Email  :  Jojo@email.com
====================
Name   :  Jojo
Phone  :  0896
Email  :  Jojo@email.com
```

instead, I want it to be:

```
====================
Name   :  Jojo
Phone  :  0896
Email  :  Jojo@email.com
```

I believe this happen because when I search for "jo" there is 2 value of "jo" which is in "Name" and "Email"

So, how do I ignore one of them?

Comment: Whats the point of iterating over `value.items()` twice?

Comment: where you want to search for text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is because Your code will continue to run even if the value is found.**

You can just add a break if the value was found.

```
cnt_lst = {     'Jojo': {'Name ': "Jojo",
                            'Phone': "0896",
                            'Email': "Jojo@email.com"},
                'Johan': {'Name ': "Johan",
                            'Phone': "0878",
                            'Email': "2@email.com"},
                'John': {'Name ': "John",
                            'Phone': "0815",
                            'Email': "3@email.com"}
                }

search = "jo"
info = False

for key, value in cnt_lst.items():   
    for subject, score in value.items():
        if search in score:
            info = True
            print("=" * 20)
            for subject, score in value.items():
                print(subject,' : ',score)
            break # -- Edited

if not info:
    print("\nNo info was found!")
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this solve my problem. You really are a lifesaver for python beginner like me